# Eclipse is not allowing me to write the method for finding MiddleElement

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm writing the method to find the middle element from the given 3 numbers but eclipse is not allowing me to do so. Please help me what should I do? The code is below:

```
public class MiddleElement {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 5;
        int y = 1;
        int z = 4;

        int[] a = {x,y,z};

        int length = a.length;

        Bubblesort(a,length);

        System.out.println("Sorted Elements are:");
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){

            System.out.print(a[i]);
        }

    }


    //Method to Bubble Sort the Elements

    public static void Bubblesort(int[] a , int len){

                int i,j,temp;

                    for (i = 0; i < len;i++){

                            for( j = 1; j < (len-1); j++){

                                if(a[j-1]>a[j]){
                                    temp = a[j-1];
                                    a[j-1] = a[j];
                                    a[j] = temp;

                                }
                            }
                    }// End of Method Bubblesort


    public static int findMiddle(int[] a){






    }

    }// End of Main Method

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Eclipse is not allowing me"? I note that you've got "End of Main method" after the end of findMiddle, which doesn't sound ideal...

Comment: Eclipse is complaining because findMiddle doesnt return nothing, just put return 0 to avoid it

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: @anakata Better yet, return 42.

Comment: Just as a side note: Your `BubbleSort` logic does not make sense and would not work for arrays with more elements.

Comment: Also, when you indent your code properly, you don't need comments telling you which brace closes which brace.

Comment: @anakata After adding `return 0` I'm getting error message that void methods cannot return. I'm wondering why?

Comment: And I'm getting ` public static int findMiddle(int[] a){` multiple markers at this line error in the above code.

Comment: Thanks all ! I got it from the post below. It's working. The braces in bubble sort was missing. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing brace from the `Bubblesort` method. Without it the compiler complains about the illegal `public` keyword modifer intended for the subsequent `findMiddle` method.

```
public static void Bubblesort(int[] a , int len){

   int i,j,temp;
   for (i = 0; i < len;i++) {
      for( j = 1; j < (len-1); j++) {
       ...
      }
   }// End of Method Bubblesort
} <-- add this
```

Make sure to return a value from the `findMiddle` method.

Aside: Java naming conventions indicate that methods begin with a *lowercase* letter and use camelCase such as `bubbleSort`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need a closing brace to end your `Bubblesort` method.  You claim that this line

```
}// End of Method Bubblesort
```

ends the method, but it doesn't.  I count 4 `{` and 3 `}` between the start of the method and that comment.  The Java compiler disallows declaring a method within a method.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to nest the `findMiddle(int[])` inside the other method. The corrected code is below:

```
public class MiddleElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 5;
        int y = 1;
        int z = 4;

        int[] a = { x, y, z };

        int length = a.length;

        Bubblesort(a, length);

        System.out.println("Sorted Elements are:");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            System.out.print(a[i]);
        }

    }// End of Main Method

    // Method to Bubble Sort the Elements

    public static void Bubblesort(int[] a, int len) {

        int i, j, temp;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            for (j = 1; j < (len - 1); j++) {

                if (a[j - 1] > a[j]) {
                    temp = a[j - 1];
                    a[j - 1] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;

                }
            }
        }

    }// End of Method Bubblesort

    public static int findMiddle(int[] a) {

        return 0;
    }

}
```